# how remove or modify "services" from wso2 esb 5.0.0 proxy uri address

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

The default endpoint URI format is like this:

- http://{host}:{port}/services/{Proxy Service Name}

I'd like to have something like:

- http://{host}:{port}/{Proxy Service Name}

or

- http://{host}:{port}/{custom path to sevices}/{Proxy Service Name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to have a proxy before it where you define the endpoint the way you want it. This also helps to only expose endpoints/ports that you actually want to expose.